# How to submit a Linux module upstream?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules

I've written a useful kernel module for a specific fan controller that I want to submit upstream.

Where can I find an address to submit my module? Do I need it make GPL or can I use a less restrictive licence?

Answer (score 8):

Read the documentation about [Submitting Drivers](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SubmittingDrivers) as well as about [Submitting Patches](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SubmittingPatches):

1. You can find the appropriate address in the `MAINTAINERS` file
2. You driver must be licensed under GPL but you can dual-license it, e.g. put it under `GPL` and a `BSD` license.